# EPS has a black background

Tags: eps

Why the EPS figure generated by LaTeX has a black background?

The example in http://roth.cs.kuleuven.be/w-ess/index.php/Creating_LaTeX_figures_with_the_use_packages_tikz_and_pgfplots#Export_as_eps is used to generate the EPS figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
 compat=1.3,
 tick label style={font=\small},
 label style={font=\small},
 legend style={font=\footnotesize}
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=fig/]
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}

\title{\LaTeX\ plots with \texttt{tikz} and \texttt{pgfplots}}
\author{Roel Van Beeumen}
\date{April 17, 2012}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


% == A first plot ======================================== %
\section{A first plot}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\tikzsetnextfilename{first-plot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sqrt{|x|}$,
 axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
 ymax=2.1,xmax=4.4]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-4:4,samples=201]
 {sqrt(abs(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]



% == A second plot ======================================= %
\section{A second plot}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\tikzsetnextfilename{second-plot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
[xlabel=Dof,ylabel=Error,
 width=\textwidth]
\addplot file{datafile1a.dat};
\addplot file{datafile1b.dat};
\legend{Case 1,Case 2}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4-5]



% == A third plot ======================================== %
\section{A third plot}

\lipsum[6]
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\tikzsetnextfilename{third-plot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=Dof,ylabel=Error,width=\textwidth]
\addplot table[x=dof1,y=error1] {datafile2.dat};
\addplot table[x=dof2,y=error2] {datafile2.dat};
\legend{Case 1,Case 2}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% -------------------------------------------------------- %
\end{figure}
\lipsum[7]


\end{document}
```

Terminal command: `latex -shell-escape example.tex`

Further information
(1) black background Check the figure in https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gyxm8gzd2p5jfdu/AABqrV27uLmoxut0Qu98mCQca?dl=0.                                                                                                          (2) Texmaker Version 4.5 is used.                                                                             (3)  *File List*

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lipsum.sty    2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2013/10/03 v1.9 Data Visualization (1.9)
fig/first-plot.eps
fig/second-plot.eps
fig/third-plot.eps
 ***********
```

*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   dvips.def    2016/07/10 v3.1a Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2016/08/10 v1.14 Data Visualization (1.14)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
fig/first-plot.eps
fig/second-plot.eps
fig/third-plot.eps

---

After updating to the latest version, the problem is still there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please provide a complete, small LaTeX document that shows the behaviour that you describe, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? This makes it easier for us to understand and investigate the problem. Just use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/332363/edit) to add the code to your post.

Comment: From this link http://roth.cs.kuleuven.be/w-ess/index.php/Creating_LaTeX_figures_with_the_use_packages_tikz_and_pgfplots#Export_as_eps, section "Export as eps", source code http://roth.cs.kuleuven.be/w-ess/index.php/File:Example-export-eps.tar.bz2, terminal command latex -shell-escape example.tex

Comment: The pdf/ps files generated from this site look perfectly normal, without black background. Can you check the log files (also those in the `fig` subdirectory) for error messages or warnings? Moreover, what do you mean by black background? Are the plots missing altogether, or are they surrounded by a black border? Last point: Which TeX distribution do you use? TeXLive 2016 or an older one? Add the command `\listfiles` as the first line of `example.tex` and post the lines from `example.log` between `*File List*` and `***********`.

Comment: Check the figure in https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gyxm8gzd2p5jfdu/AABqrV27uLmoxut0Qu98mCQca?dl=0.   Texmaker Version 4.5 is used.

Comment: Your TeX distribution (not Texmaker, this is just a tool on top, a kind of "intelligent" editor) is outdated. Relevant packages are `tikz` (you have version 2.10 from 2010, the current version is 3.0.1a from 2015) and `pgfplots` (you have 1.9 from 2013, the current version is 1.14 from 2016). It is hardly possible to analyze your problem anywhere else than on your computer, and the result most probably will be: update your TeX distribution to get rid of the old bugs.